# How do we insert a boost ptree as a node in another boost ptree?

Tags: boost-propertytree

I would like to serialize a hierarchical data structure in C++. The project I'm working on uses boost so I'm using `boost::property_tree::ptree` as my data node structure.

We have higher level structures like `Person` which contain instances of lower level structures like `Job` (each person has a job). `Person` and `Job` each implement a `ptreeify` method. The idea is to serialize the hierarchy by having each object call `ptreeify` on each other object it contains. The resulting sub objects' property trees are then inserted as nodes in the containing object's property tree. The problem is that I can't figure out how to actually do the insertion.

Following [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590370/boost-property-tree-iterators-to-an-element-for-inserting/7604137#7604137) leads to a run time error. I lack the knowledge/experience needed to understand what's causing it. See code below.

I also found [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154107/how-do-i-merge-update-a-boostproperty-treeptree) but I do not understand the answer at all and I suspect the use of `insert` avoids complication found there.

**Question: how do you insert a property tree as a node in another property tree?**

Here is the actual code. The run time error occurs within `Person::ptreeify`.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;
using namespace std;

struct Job{
    std::string title;
    int hoursPerWeek;
    ptree ptreeify(void); //return a ptree representing this Job
    };

ptree Job::ptreeify(){
    ptree pt;
    pt.put("title", title);
    pt.put("hours", hoursPerWeek);
    return pt;
    }

struct Person{
    std::string name;
    Job job;
    ptree ptreeify(void); //return a ptree representing this Person
                          //This must iterively call ptreeify on all sub-objects
    void save(const std::string &filename); //write this Person to file
    };

ptree Person::ptreeify(){
    ptree pt;
    pt.put("name", name);
    pt.put("job", "");

    ptree jobPt;
    jobPt = job.ptreeify();
    std::cout << "Program dies after this line" << std::endl;
    //This next line causes a run time error
    pt.insert(pt.get_child("job").begin(), jobPt.begin(), jobPt.end());
    return pt;
    }

void Person::save(const std::string &filename){
    ptree pt;
    pt = ptreeify();
    write_json(filename, pt);
    };

int main(){
    Person myPerson;
    myPerson.name = "Julius";

    Job myJob;
    myJob.title = "monkey";
    myJob.hoursPerWeek = 40;

    myPerson.job = myJob;

    myPerson.save("myPerson.dat");
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out this is really simple. You use `put_child`

```
ptree Person::ptreeify(){
    ptree pt;
    pt.put("name", name);

    ptree jobPt;
    jobPt = job.ptreeify();
    pt.put_child("job", jobPt);
    return pt;
    }
```